# Quickchart Wordcloud API is returning spread and small text

Tags: url, query-string, word-cloud, querystringparameter

I am trying to get the Quickchart Wordcloud API to work, however, I get very spread apart and small text.

This used to work fine (I tested it a few weeks ago), but something seems to have changed to cause the issue you can test below.

[Example](https://quickchart.io/wordcloud?rotation=0&format=png&height=176px&width=506px&font-family=sans-serif&removeStopwords=true&text=Four%20score%20and%20seven%20years%20ago%20our%20fathers%20brought%20forth%20on%20this%20continent,%20a%20new%20nation,%20conceived%20in%20Liberty,%20and%20dedicated%20to%20the%20proposition%20that%20all%20men%20are%20created%20equal.Now%20we%20are%20engaged%20in%20a%20great%20civil%20war,%20testing%20whether%20that%20nation,%20or%20any%20nation%20so%20conceived%20and%20so%20dedicated,%20can%20long%20endure.%20We%20are%20met%20on%20a%20great%20battle-field%20of%20that%20war.%20We%20have%20come%20to%20dedicate%20a%20portion%20of%20that%20field,%20as%20a%20final%20resting%20place%20for%20those%20who%20here%20gave%20their%20lives%20that%20that%20nation%20might%20live.%20It%20is%20altogether%20fitting%20and%20proper%20that%20we%20should%20do%20this.But,%20in%20a%20larger%20sense,%20we%20can%20not%20dedicate%E2%80%94we%20can%20not%20consecrate%E2%80%94we%20can%20not%20hallow%E2%80%94this%20ground.%20The%20brave%20men,%20living%20and%20dead,%20who%20struggled%20here,%20have%20consecrated%20it,%20far%20above%20our%20poor%20power%20to%20add%20or%20detract.%20The%20world%20will%20little%20note,%20nor%20long%20remember%20what%20we%20say%20here,%20but%20it%20can%20never%20forget%20what%20they%20did%20here.%20It%20is%20for%20us%20the%20living,%20rather,%20to%20be%20dedicated%20here%20to%20the%20unfinished%20work%20which%20they%20who%20fought%20here%20have%20thus%20far%20so%20nobly%20advanced.%20It%20is%20rather%20for%20us%20to%20be%20here%20dedicated%20to%20the%20great%20task%20remaining%20before%20us%E2%80%94that%20from%20these%20honored%20dead%20we%20take%20increased%20devotion%20to%20that%20cause%20for%20which%20they%20gave%20the%20last%20full%20measure%20of%20devotion%E2%80%94that%20we%20here%20highly%20resolve%20that%20these%20dead%20shall%20not%20have%20died%20in%20vain%E2%80%94that%20this%20nation,%20under%20God,%20shall%20have%20a%20new%20birth%20of%20freedom%E2%80%94and%20that%20government%20of%20the%20people,%20by%20the%20people,%20for%20the%20people,%20shall%20not%20perish%20from%20the%20earth.)

Apart from the text, you can see the querystring below:

```
rotation=0&format=png&height=176px&width=506px&font-family=sans-serif&removeStopwords=true&text=
```

Any insight into how I can get this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain this API and want to apologize for the trouble you encountered over the last few weeks.  This *should* be fixed now with no action required on your end.

Some background on the trouble: the underlying library, d3-cloud, is a bit finicky and under certain conditions it will not show top words if they are too large.  We attempt to resolve this by sizing the words explicitly, but this can be imprecise because we do not have full rendering information.  In the long term, I'd like to move to a more robust rendering library but for now we're tuning the workaround.

Related issues in the d3-cloud repo:

- https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/issues/166
- https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/issues/159
- https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/issues/36